# Custom users list in admin area of wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to WordPress i need to modify users list in admin area.    Some information of user is blank so i want to display default value at blank space.

I have tried to modified `$wp_list_table->display()` function within `wp-admin\wp-includes\class-wp-list-table.php`  but no luck.

Please help me.

Comment: You just want to modify the content of users list in backend for displaying purpose?

Comment: Thank you so much for reply @RaunakGupta  yes i want to modify the content of users list for displaying purpose if some column have empty value.

Comment: Tip: DO NOT modify any of the core Wordpress files. These will be overwritten when you next update Wordpress.

Comment: Check it out this http://codingbin.com/display-custom-table-data-wordpress-admin/

Answer (score 0):

`WP_User_Query` is a class, defined in `wp-includes/user.php`, that allows querying WordPress database tables '**wp_users**' and '**wp_usermeta**'. This class was introduced in Version 3.1 and as a result, the WP_User_Search class got deprecated.

**Display Users by Roles**

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Administrator' ) );
```

**Display all users except a specific list of users**

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'exclude' => array( 4, 5, 6 ) ) );
```

**Display users based on a keyword search, only on login and email columns**

```
$args = array(
    'search'         => 'Rami',
    'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_email' )
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

For More [refer this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)